# Entity Framework: DBContext: How to Detecting entity exists in Database

Tags: entity-framework

Given the following example:

```
public class Parent 
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public Child Child {get;set;}
}


public class Child 
{
    public Guid ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

I want to save a Parent object instance, with a Child instance assigned to it. The fact here is: the given child object already exists in the Database,

```
 Parent p = new Parent();
 p.ID = Guid.NewGuid();

 // Get the Child Object 
 Child c = GetTheChild(...);
 p.Child = c;

SaveParent ( p );
```

in function Save Parent, the following code is implemented:

```
public void SaveParent ( Parent p )
{
     using (MyContext context = new ClinicContext())
     {
        context.Parents.Add( P );
        context.SaveChanges();

     }
}
```

Now the problem comes: since the child in this example already exists in the database, but when adding the parent in the context DBSet, the entity c given also holds a entry state of "Added", guess what? DBContext tries to save another child record with a duplicated Key!

Any body know how to solve this? I am thinking whether there is a way to turn a Insert into Update if the Entity Framework can detect the records already exists in the database.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you add an entity all releated entity will be added. If you attach an entity all related entities will be attached. In your case you want to add the Parent entity and then attach the child entity. What you could also try would be to use foreign keys and add parent and just set the foreign key to the related child Id. This way you would not have to bring the entity to the client to create the relationship (you need to know the key of the related entity though).

Answer (score 0):

How are you getting the child? The child should be attached to the same context you save the parent on.

My guess is your GetTheChild function uses a new context - which means when you return the child is detached and for all intents and purposes EF figures its been 'added'

As panel said you can just add a foreign key and just set the child's key instead of the child itself but there seems to be some design issues you should address.

Answer (score 0):

I guess GetTheChild() will return a child from database. So, all you need to do is call ChangeObjectState method to mark the child as Unchanged before calling SaveChanges.

```
var osm = context.ObjectStateManager;
osm.ChangeObjectState(child, EntityState.Unchanged);
```